# Xamarin - slide element within Frame outside of view

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Not really sure how to properly describe my problem using correct wording as I'm new to Xamarin and Xaml.

I have a Frame with several StackLayouts within and I want to slide a specific StackLayout outside the Frame without showing it outside the Frame.

I can currently do this with:

XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
    xmlns:mr="clr-namespace:MR.Gestures;assembly=MR.Gestures"
    x:Class="iRemote.UI.Maps.LocationFinderMap"
    xmlns:map="clr-namespace:iRemote.Location"
    Title="Location Finder">

    <Frame HasShadow="true" OutlineColor="Color.Black" WidthRequest="700" HeightRequest="300" Padding="3"
           BackgroundColor="White">
        <mr:StackLayout x:Name="sl_main" Padding="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="200">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Parcel #" />
                    <Entry x:Name="txtParcel" WidthRequest="100" />
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnClose" BackgroundColor="#0786a3" BorderRadius="30" TextColor="White"
                            Text="Close" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Meter #" />
                    <Entry x:Name="txtMeter" WidthRequest="100" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <SearchBar x:Name="search" Placeholder="Search" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Padding="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <mr:Image x:Name="img_map" Source="down" HeightRequest="19" WidthRequest="32" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="sl_map" Padding="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="5"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="true" WidthRequest="300">
                <map:ExtendedMap
                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    x:Name="MP"
                    IsShowingUser="true"
                    MapType="Street" />
            </StackLayout>
        </mr:StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentPage>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
if (panelShowing)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle(this.Width - sl_map.Width, sl_map.Y, sl_map.Width, sl_map.Height);
    sl_map.LayoutTo(rect, 250, Easing.CubicIn);
}
else
{
    var rect = new Rectangle(this.Width + sl_map.Width - 40, sl_map.Y, sl_map.Width, sl_map.Height);
    sl_map.LayoutTo(rect, 200, Easing.CubicOut);
}
```

However, sl_map simply just shows outside the frame. I want it to not be visible as it crosses the border of the frame. I hope that's clear enough. Again, sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology. I'm a WinForms guy.

Comment: The IsClippedToBounds - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Layout.IsClippedToBounds/ - property might do the trick for you.  Depending on the platforms you want to support, because I've found it is rather buggy.

Comment: Worked like a charm...thanks